# Laravel and Vuejs: how to use vuejs in laravel multi page application

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i have a multiple pages application that i build in Laravel, i want to use Vuejs in some parts of the application.i have six modules customers,invoice,products,stocks,dashboard,analysis.
The customers,products,stock are just basic crud so i use Laravel.

How to do i turn the invoice,analysis,dashboard in single page applications. i have tried but when i use chromes back arrow to redirect back, i get 404|page not found.

this is my invoice/index.blade.php file, it loads everything corrently

```
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <invoice-index></invoice-index>
          </div>
      </div>
```

inside my  component,   when i click on any link i a 404 error. i have tried router-link , 'a href' none is redirecting me to invoiceform

```
   <template>
     <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="row pb-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="tile-header">
                    <a href="/invoices/create" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">new Invoice</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tile-body">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> # </th>
                        <th style="with:20%"> Date </th>
                        <th> Number </th>
                        <th> Customer </th>
                        <th> Due Date </th>
                        <th> Total </th>

                        <th style="width:100px; min-width:100px;" class="text-center text-danger"><i class="fa fa-bolt"> </i></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="invoice in allInvoices" :key="invoice.id" class="py-0 text-center" >
                        <td class="align-middle py-0">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-info font-weight-bold">
                                {{ invoice.id }}
                            </a> 
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 10%">{{invoice.date}}</td>
                        <td >{{invoice.number}}</td>
                        <td >{{invoice.customer_id}}</td>
                        <td >{{invoice.due_date}}</td>
                        <td >{{invoice.total}}</td>

                        <td class="text-center">
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

             </div>
         </div>
  </div>
```

I this is my routes

```
 const router = new VueRouter({
routes: [

    {
        path:'/dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path:'/invoices',
        component: InvoiceIndex
    },
    {
        path:'/invoices/create',
        component: InvoiceForm
    }

],
mode:'history'
```

});

Answer (score 0):

For SPA with Vue.js, You must define links using `vue-router`. When defined routes using `vue-router`, you can use your vue.js routes and only calls components. So you can build SPA. You can find details on here.

https://router.vuejs.org/

I hope it helps you. But It can be hard to implement if you are new on Vue.js